# Android Firefox does not show web push messages when in background

Tags: android, firefox, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API),

> The Push API gives web applications the ability to receive messages pushed to them from a server, whether or not the web app is in the foreground, or even currently loaded, on a user agent.

If properly implemented, this seems to suggest that Android Firefox would be able to handle push notifications, even though the app is in the background.

Indeed, this works completely fine for me on Android Chrome, but for Android Firefox, as soon as the browser has been in the background for a short period of time (a couple of hours seems to be enough on the Android 10 devices I tested this on), push notifications stop coming through, and they do not even show up once the browser is loaded again, even if I specify a TTL of 60*60*24.

More concretely, I have examples of users that subscribe to web push messages, and when sending the messages to the Mozilla push server, I'll always get 201 responses. The messages show up just fine when the browser is in the foreground, but again, after a while in the background, they'll stop showing up. I've specified `"normal"` for the `"Urgency"` header, and the output of Python's `int(time.time()) + (12 * 60 * 60)` for the VAPID expiry time.

I first suspected the TTL to be the culprit, but according to [this blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2016/02/20/webpushs-new-requirement-ttl-header/), I shouldn't be getting 201s if that were the issue.

My service worker looks as follows:

```js
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
    if (event.data) {
        data = event.data.json()
        showLocalNotification(data.title, data.message, self.registration);
    }
});

const showLocalNotification = (title, body, swRegistration) => {
    const options = {
        body: body,
        badge: "/badge.png",
        icon: "/plug-512.png",
    };
    swRegistration.showNotification(title, options);
};
```

I've tried adding a trivial event handler for `fetch` but that makes no difference either.

I use `pywebpush` to make the requests to the push servers and `py_vapid` to handle signing; the concrete implementation takes a string called `data` and the user-provided `subscription_info`, and creates a request as follows:

```py
import time
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from pywebpush import WebPusher
from py_vapid import Vapid

def send_push(data, subscription_info):
    subscription_info = row
    pusher = WebPusher(subscription_info)
    url = urlparse(subscription_info['endpoint'])
    aud = "{}://{}".format(url.scheme, url.netloc)
    vapid_claims = {'sub': 'mailto:mail@example.com'}
    vapid_claims['aud'] = aud
    vapid_claims['exp'] = int(time.time()) + (12 * 60 * 60)
    vv = Vapid.from_string('my-key')
    vapid_headers = vv.sign(vapid_claims)
    vapid_headers['Urgency'] = 'normal'
    resp = pusher.send(data, vapid_headers, ttl=60*60*24)
    assert resp.status_code == 201
```

The app is currently [live here](https://gr%C3%B8nstr%C3%B8m.nu).

Comment: found a solution?